# How can I scroll a particular section of a dynamic web page using selenium webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have found many reference that scroll the entire webpage but I am looking for a particular section to scroll. I am working on marketwatch.com - section - latest news tab. How can I scroll just this latest news tab using selenium webdriver?

Below is my code which returns the heading of the news but keeps repeating same headings.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver


count = 0   
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/newsviewer")

pageSource = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')

arkodiv = soup.find("ol", class_="viewport")

while browser.find_element_by_tag_name('ol'):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    div = list(arkodiv.find_all('div', class_= "nv-details"))

    heading = []
    Data_11 = list(soup.find_all("div", class_ = "nv-text-cont"))          

    datetime = list(arkodiv.find_all("li", timestamp = True))
    for sa in datetime:
        sh = sa.find("div", class_ = "nv-text-cont")
        if sh.find("a", class_ = True):
            di = sh.text.strip()
            di = di.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
        else:
            continue
        print di
        heading.append((di))       
        count = count+1         


    if 'End of Results' in arkodiv:
        print 'end'
        break
    else:
        continue
    print count
```

Comment: `pageSource = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')` - these two lines should be used after the scrolling is done. Otherwise you won't get the new HTML.

Comment: Complete the scrolling first, in a separate loop, and then start scraping with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar That doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: @drec4s, of course it doesn't solve his problem. That's why it's a comment and not an answer. But, without making that change, any other change wouldn't matter as he is scraping from the original page source; hence any scrolling won't matter.

Comment: If you want, you can add this to your answer to make it a complete working solution.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar That would be a good exercise for a beginner to figure out, right? ;) Anyway, there were other things that needed revision, and I updated the answer with a full working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the script you are executing scrolls to the bottom of the page.

To keep scrolling inside the element fetching news you need to replace this:

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

with this:

```
browser.execute_script("document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('viewport')[0].scrollTop = 999999")
```

**EDIT**

This is the complete working solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver


count = 0   
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/newsviewer")

while browser.find_element_by_tag_name('ol'):

    pageSource = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')
    arkodiv = soup.find("ol", class_="viewport")
    browser.execute_script("document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('viewport')[0].scrollTop = 999999")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    div = list(arkodiv.find_all('div', class_= "nv-details"))

    heading = set()
    Data_11 = list(soup.find_all("div", class_ = "nv-text-cont"))          

    datetime = list(arkodiv.find_all("li", timestamp = True))
    for sa in datetime:
        sh = sa.find("div", class_ = "nv-text-cont")
        if sh.find("a", class_ = True):
            di = sh.text.strip()
            di = di.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
        else:
            continue
        print di
        heading.add((di))       
        count = count+1         


    if 'End of Results' in arkodiv:
        print 'end'
        break
    else:
        continue
    print count
```

**EDIT 2**

You may also want to change how you store the headers, since the way you currently do keeps duplicates inside the list. Changed it to a `set` so that doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. Even when I use "set" to store results I get duplicates. How can I fix it?